# Create Trigger to Run Script Only When New Row is Added to Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have what seems to be a relatively simple task, but cannot seem to figure it out. I've written a script that creates a calendar event when a form is submitted. We will no longer be using the form (moving to AppSheet instead) so, I need the trigger to fire ONLY when a new row is added. I believe "onChange" is the way to go about this, but I only want the script to run when a row is added, not when it is edited, deleted, or changed in any other way. Any suggestions?

```
// Create Calendar Event From Spreadsheet

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

// Calendar to output requests
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('youremail@gmail.com');

// Creates an object from the last row
function getSubmission() {
  this.timestamp = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
  this.accountNumber = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();
  this.contactLastName = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue();
  this.contactFirstName = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 4).getValue();
  this.contactPhoneNumber = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 5).getValue();
  this.contactEmail = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 6).getValue();
  this.userLastName = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 7).getValue();
  this.userFirstName = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 8).getValue();
  this.userPhoneNumber = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 9).getValue();
  this.userEmail = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 10).getValue();
  this.streetAddress = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 11).getValue();
  this.city = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 12).getValue();
  this.state = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 13).getValue();
  this.zipCode = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 14).getValue();
  this.type = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 15).getValue();
  this.equipment = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 16).getValue();
  this.typeOfLead = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 17).getValue();
  this.sourceOfLead = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 18).getValue();
  this.notes = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 19).getValue();
  this.date = new Date(sheet.getRange(lastRow, 20).getValue());
  this.appointmentStart = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 21).getValue();
  this.appointmentEnd = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 22).getValue();
  this.direction = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 23).getValue();
  this.callOnWay = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 24).getValue();
  return this;
}

//  Creates a calendar event using the last row
function updateCalendar(request) {
  request.date.setHours(request.appointmentStart.getHours());
  request.date.setMinutes(request.appointmentStart.getMinutes());
  var endTime = new Date(request.date);
  endTime.setHours(request.appointmentEnd.getHours());
  endTime.setMinutes(request.appointmentEnd.getMinutes())
  var event = calendar.createEvent(
    request.state + " " + request.direction + " EST " + request.contactLastName + ", " + request.contactFirstName + " " + request.callOnWay,
    request.date,
    endTime
  )
  .setLocation(request.streetAddress + " " + request.city + ", " + request.state + " " + request.zipCode
  )
  .setDescription("Account # " + request.accountNumber + "\n" + "\n" + request.contactFirstName + " " + request.contactLastName + "\n" + request.contactPhoneNumber + "\n" + request.contactEmail + "\n" + "\n" + "Notes: " + request.type + " - " + request.equipment + ". " + request.notes + ".\n" + "Lead: " + request.typeOfLead + " - " + request.sourceOfLead + "." + "\n" + "\n" + "Jim: Scanned:____    " + "Inv. Adj:____    " + "QB:____    " + "Est. SL:____" + "\n" + "\n" + "Tracy: QB:____" + "    Scan:____" + "    Letter:____" + "    Lead Sheet:____" + "    Ref. Check #:____"
  )
}

// --------------Main--------------
function main() {
  var request = getSubmission();
  updateCalendar(request);
}
```

Comment: If it is a Google Form, you should use onFormSubmit instead of onChange. If you are using a custom HTML form, you would be better off creating the event right after

Comment: ArtiBucco, I was using onFormSubmit, but no longer will be, as submissions will not be received via a google form. I need to trigger the script only when new rows are added.

Answer (score 1):

Use onChange with changeType = "INSERT_ROW"

Your code will run probably ten times faster if you use one getValues();

I would just correlate the column numbers to the names with an  array and an object.

I'm not going to actually do it.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

By the way using the lastRow for a form submission is a bad idea.  You should use event object values or namedValues.  If you get a lot of submissions at the same time your code will have problems.

function getSubmission(e) {
if(e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") {
//put code here
}
}

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Cooper. I am quite new to writing on app script. I assume I will need to run the following code to create the trigger. How do I implement changeType = "INSERT_ROW" ? all of my attempts to implement result in "cannot read property 'changeType'."                     `function createTrigger(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("notify")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onChange()
  .create();
}`

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Seems closer to working now, having an issue with what is identified as a "INSERT_ROW" though. Please see the answer I submitted.

Comment: Triggers only get activated by user action.  Other script or formula actions do not generate triggers.

Comment: The insert row trigger only occurs when a user actually inserts a new row not types into a row that's already there.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I did figure out a way to make it work. I am sure it is not the proper way to do so, but setting `changeType == "OTHER"` allows the script to run as desired when data is submitted via AppSheet. Again, not the proper way, but a workaround for the time being. We use the sheet and script to collect leads we (3 employees) are entering via app sheet and create a calendar event in google calendar for their estimate appointment. We always verify that the event shows up on gcal, so should notice as soon as any issues arise.

Comment: I didn't know it would do that.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that INSERT_ROW only registers when a row is manually inserted (right click, insert row above or below). It does not run when data is added via AppSheet, a form, or typed in. Below is the code I have added o my script which behaves as expected when a row is manually inserted. Is there any way to have the script run when data is entered into a new row via an outside source or typed into the row?

```
function runMain(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    if (e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") {
    main();
    }
}
```

Here is a simple standalone test script I have been using to check what inputs into the sheet fire the script.

```
function notify(e) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("youremail@gmail.com.com", "Row Added", "A row was added to your sheet.");
}

function runNotify(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    if (e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") {
    notify(e);
    }
}
```